# MSChart Callout horizontal alignment to datapoint WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, annotations, mschart, callouts

I'm in need of help please,  I'm using MSChart for .NET4.0 WinForms in C Sharp and right now when I plot my chart the annotations are all over the place.

[image: Callouts are all over the place! it's really messy!]

What I really like is for this (I manually moved the Callouts after to make this screenshot)

[image: Manually positioned Callout with mouse after chart render]

So what I am wondering, is there a way I can make sure that ALL Callout annotations stay absolutely on top of bottom vertically of the respective datapoint anchor?  I don't wish for the Callouts to move left or right....

Thanks everyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSChart uses SmartLabel Technology to display labels.

You can change this property

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].SmartLabels.MovingDirection =  
LabelAlignment.Bottom | LabelAlignment.Top;
```

You can check these links

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24644/What-can-SmartLabels-Technology-do-for-me
http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/UsingSmartLabels.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.smartlabelstyle.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I did see this, however 1 thing, I don't have SmartLabels property, only SmartLabelStyle & LabelAlignmentStyle properties which I've tried but doesn't seem to make any differences.

Maybe because I have many series in the Chart, there maybe a default setting that I must override somewhere?  Any pointers of usual hick-ups would be helpful as I believe I have checked everywhere now without avail... thanks

Comment: Try this property and check if it works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotationsmartlabelstyle.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the MSDN link, after reading that I believe I am doing everything right with SmartLabelStyle :D it's just not working for me yet :(  are there any common pitfalls I should be aware of that I might have stuck my feet on?

Comment: I think I've worked it out, after cleaning up the code, maybe because I am using a live datafeed and I am dynamically creating annotation objects to dynamically add to the chart, I cleared all annotation chart properties and only declared them each time I create a new instance of an annotation to add to the referred Chart. The only property I could not find when instantiating a new annotation was Chart1...SmartLabelStyle.IsOverlappedHidden = false;  so I set this for each Chart area I have.  My chart is still not perfect but it's much better now, thanks Quantbuff :D